# Is this the most efficient way to write code?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub test
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F4:F" & LR).Formula = “=d4*-1”
    Range("F4:F" & LR).Copy
    Range("F4:F" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End sub
```

In my macro I do a lot of pasting values and I was just curious if there is a more efficient way to write the above code.

Comment: Where are you pasting to?

Comment: `Range("F4:F" & LR).Value = Range("F4:F" & LR).Value`. No need to copy.

Comment: @BigBen, isn't that just pasting on to itself?

Comment: @AAA, that's what OP is doing.

Comment: OK @BigBen. I figured they had some selected cell(s) already and the paste would go in there. Of course, your method is correct, especially as they are pasting by value.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quickest way what you trying to do could be:

```
Sub Test()

Dim LR As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("F4:F" & LR).Value = .Evaluate("D4:D" & LR & "*-1")
End With

End Sub
```

For future reference, copy/paste when needing `.PasteSpecial` requires excel to store data in the `Clipboard` which means it takes more time to run your macro. Just copy/paste a range will bypass this when you specify the [`Destination`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) parameter. Ommiting this will again store the range on the `Clipboard`.

Just in general, you can mostly avoid using copy/paste!

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen suggested, but with the use of a `With/End With` statement...

```
Sub test()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("F4:F" & LR)
        .Formula = "=D4*-1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```